# Simulating a game where each player has a different probability of winning?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, statistics, simulation

Say I have 4 players:

```
Player 1 wins 50% of his games
Player 2 wins 20% of his games
Player 3 wins 90% of his games
Player 4 wins 20% of his games
```

I need a way to model different players playing together and randomly selecting a winner, but such that the winner makes sense.

My first idea was to do this:

If my random number falls between 1 and 50, player 1 wins, if my random number falls between 51 and 101, player 2 wins, if it falls between 102 and 192, player 3 wins, and if it falls between  193 and 203, player 4 wins.

I pick a number between 1 and 203 to determine the winner. Assuming my random number is uniformly distributed, I should expect to get what I want.

I'm wondering if there is a more mathematical way to do this or if this is the only way? (leveraging the language c++)

Comment: If they're playing against each other, the percentages should add up to 100%

Comment: @BilltheLizard The thing is, the data I have is based on past games. What percentage of their past games did these people win. If 2 people win 90% of the time, it's anybody's game, but if 1 wins 5% of the time and the other 50% of the time, there's a good chance the 50% person will win agains the 5% guy.

Comment: @Milo I guess you will have to normalize the values.

Comment: You could use [Elo ratings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system).

Comment: I am presuming the winning percentages are against all players not just the other three?

Comment: Are ties permissible?  If so how are they figured into the winning percentage?  The two common ways are 1) counting ties as half wins 2) not counting ties at all.

Comment: So these are not games against each other necessarily but games won in general. Then I think you could simply add up the percentages of each player in the game and take each individual's percentage score as a fractional value of that whole.

Comment: I do like ELO ratings...  Harkness wrote a book many years ago describing how the US Chess Federation implemented an ELO based system.  Getting into the numbers and algorithms it was 'easy' to generate a Rating based on win percentage.  Once you have ratings you can then calculate head to head probability of winning based on difference of ratings.

Comment: @Axalo @ Galik @ Milo Each of your approaches are equivalent.

Comment: There are degrees of freedom.  Imagine if those players all played the same pool of 10 opponents, numbered 0 thru 9.  Each *always* beat some opponents, and lost to others, but they plaued all 10 evenly.  The skill level would be 5 2 9 2.  You'd expect if those 4 play, 9 would always win in this model.  In a sense, the "shapness" of the skill curve can vary.  This also assimes simple linear skill (no rock paper scissors problem: prot red/black in a sly/necro dominated metagame may show up with 50% win rate, but slaughter 90%ers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will change this comment into an answer since I have more:

I like ELO ratings.  Harkness wrote a book many years ago describing how the US Chess Federation implemented its rating with an extension of a basic ELO system.  As an aside when a new player would be establish his rating the first 25 games were based on a strictly ELO system. (Wish I could give a reference, but my work computer won't let me navigate to any site that concerns games).

Getting into the numbers and algorithms it was 'easy' to generate a Rating based on win percentage. Once you have ratings you can then calculate head to head probability of winning based on difference of ratings.

Once you have head to probabilities then add up each players probabilities of winning against his three opponents and declare the highest total the winner.  If you want specific probabilities of a person winning the Round Robin, you can use elementary statistical analysis to calculate the variance of winning percentage over all from the sum of the individual game variances.